# How do I change the Maven-WAR plugin's cache file location?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-war-plugin

I’m using Maven 3.1.1 and using the Maven-war plugin v 2.4.  I would like to create the cache in a directory other than the ${basedir}/target/war/work directory, but I can’t seem to figure out how to configure the plugin to do that.  I tried

```
                            <plugins>
                                    <plugin>
                                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                                            <version>2.4</version>
                                            <configuration>
                                                    <useCache>true</useCache>
                                                    <workDirectory>/tmp/${project.artifactId}/war/work</workDirectory>
                                            </configuration>
                                            <goals>
                                                    <goal>inplace</goal>
                                            </goals>
                                    </plugin>
                            </plugins>
```

However, the work directory never changes.  Any idea how to configure things so that the plugin respects where I want to place the cache file?

Comment: What command are you running when you expect the output in /tmp/... ?

Comment: I'm running "mvn clean install"

Comment: Why do you like to change that directory? What is the reason to do so?

Comment: By default the cache files get generated in "target" but when I run "mvn clean install" the target directory is deleted.  Thus, my cache is re-generated each time and that defeats the purpose of one.

Comment: This won't work because you are completely mangling the lifecycle.  What is your end objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to explain what i discovered with the help of the debug flag (`mvn -X clean install`).

Default values are:

```
<workDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}/war/work"/>
<cacheFile default-value="${project.build.directory}/war/work/webapp-cache.xml"/>
```

As stated in [maven war plugin's doc](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html), workDirectory parameter is where *where overlays will be temporarily extracted*; changing it will not affect the path of the cache's file.

Instead, adding a **cacheFile** tag to configuration

```
<configuration>
  <useCache>true</useCache>
  <cacheFile>/customdir/webapp-cache.xml</cacheFile>
</configuration>
```

will override the cache's final position, resulting in:

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.4:war' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (s) archiveClasses = false
[DEBUG]   (s) attachClasses = true
[DEBUG]   (s) cacheFile = C:\customdir\webapp-cache.xml
```

Regards,
PaoloC

Answer (score 0):

Declaring `goals` directly under `plugin` is deprecated. Please use:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        <executions>
              <execution>
                         <goals>
                            <goal>inplace</goal>
                         </goals>
                   <configuration>
                         <useCache>true</useCache>
                         <workDirectory>/tmp/${project.artifactId}/war/work</workDirectory>
                   </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>                                            
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

(Note the `executions` tag).

Comment: I tried this but now no "war/work" directory gets generated anywhere.  I even tried commenting out my "<workDirectory>" configuration piece but still no cache file is generated with your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but I think the problem is that you're not associating that execution with a phase. By default the `inplace` goal is not associated with any phase (unlike `war` which is associated to the package phase)

you can try the following

```
<executions>
   <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>inplace</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
         <useCache>true</useCache>
         <workDirectory>/tmp/${project.artifactId}/war/work</workDirectory>
      </configuration>
   </execution>
</executions>
```

This should trigger the `inplace` goal when maven executes the package phase.

Comment: I tried this and this time the cache file is generated, however it is still generated in my target directory, not in the "/tmp" directory I've specified.